# Left Join fails with Unknown column in on clause

Tags: left-join

I have two queries that run against the same table(s) except the second one fails with the addition of a Left Join.

Runs Successfully

```
 SELECT *
 FROM paypal_ipn_orders 
 LEFT join itemkey on paypal_ipn_orders.item_number = itemkey.item_id 
 WHERE packing_slip_printed = 0
 AND LOWER(payment_status) = 'completed'
 AND address_name <> ''
 order by itemkey.sort_id;
```

Yet this second query Fails with "Unknown column 'paypal_ipn_orders.item_number' in 'on clause'",  Yet it runs fine with out the left join.   The Paypal_ipn_orders table does contain the item_number field.

```
SELECT *
FROM paypal_ipn_orders as table1,
(SELECT payer_email, COUNT(*) as count FROM paypal_ipn_orders GROUP BY payer_email ORDER BY count DESC) as table2
LEFT join itemkey on table1.item_number = itemkey.item_id 
WHERE table1.payer_email = table2.payer_email 
and packing_slip_printed = 0
AND LOWER(payment_status) = 'completed'
AND address_name <> ''
ORDER BY count DESC, auction_multi_item, item_number;
```

The comma after table1 is required as the (SELECT... is part of the FROM clause.

An interesting note.   I changed the order of the From clause to:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT payer_email, COUNT(*) as count FROM paypal_ipn_orders GROUP BY payer_email ORDER BY count DESC) as table1,
paypal_ipn_orders as table12
LEFT join itemkey on table2.item_number = itemkey.item_id 
WHERE table2.payer_email = table1.payer_email 
and packing_slip_printed = 0
AND LOWER(payment_status) = 'completed'
AND address_name <> ''
ORDER BY count DESC, auction_multi_item, item_number;
```

and now the error message is:  Unknown column 'table2.payer_email' in 'where clause'.   But this will not run with out the Left Join.  Giving the same Unknown column in where clause message.

FYI - This works:

```
 SELECT payer_email, COUNT(*) as count 
 FROM paypal_ipn_orders 
 WHERE packing_slip_printed = 0
 AND LOWER(payment_status) = 'completed'
 AND address_name <> ''
 GROUP BY payer_email 
 ORDER BY count DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
FROM paypal_ipn_orders table1,
```

Do you mean... `FROM paypal_ipn_orders AS table1 (...`?

Also note that comma at the end of `table1,`.  I'm not sure if that's intended?

Comment: Sorry,  it fails the same with our without the "'as' table1"   I have also tried the table name "paypal_ipn_orders" with the same results.

Comment: Okay, I'll take a hard look at this later if you're still having trouble.

Comment: Thank you John,  it is still a mystry to me.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked in the end:

```
SELECT *
        FROM (SELECT payer_email, COUNT(*) as count 
           FROM paypal_ipn_orders 
           Where packing_slip_printed = 0
           AND LOWER(payment_status) = 'completed'
           AND address_name <> '' 
           GROUP BY payer_email 
           ORDER BY count DESC) as table1,
        paypal_ipn_orders as table2
        LEFT join itemkey on table2.item_number = itemkey.item_id 
        WHERE table1.payer_email = table2.payer_email 
        and packing_slip_printed = 0
        AND LOWER(payment_status) = 'completed'
        AND address_name <> ''
        ORDER BY count DESC, auction_multi_item, sort_id
```

Comment: Thanks for posting!  Sorry I haven't had the chance to look, but I'm glad you figured it out.